# How to create table structure within select menu

Tags: html, css

Pls consider simple example with menu options below. I'd like to have the carbrand, country and date values nicely structured in a table format within the menu -so with three columns for the carbrand, country and date values.

UPDATE: added a picture with targeted format of selectbox:

[image]

How to do that? I'd try to embed the select tags within the table tags but that does not work...

```
<body>
<select size="4">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo Sweden 2012</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab Sweden 2011</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes Germany 2010</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi Germany 2009</option>
</select>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if that is possible, but I think you `<optgroup>` could help you to group the categories better.

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_optgroup.asp

```
Group related options with <optgroup> tags:

<select>
  <optgroup label="Swedish Cars">
    <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
    <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup label="German Cars">
    <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
    <option value="audi">Audi</option>
  </optgroup>
</select>
```

Comment: thnx for your reply. Unfortenately that's not what I try to achieve. The menu is supposed to have -only- the select items as described in my example code. As shown each select items has 3 descriptions, e.g. just 3 words for the carbrand, country and date. All I want is that the 3 select items with the 3 descriptions are displayed in a table format with three columns.

Comment: I understand what you are asking, however the option tag can only contain normal character data e.g. text (http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/option.html). So I don't think what you are asking for is possible using the option tag.

Comment: In that case I may need to use an alternative for select such as http://kalnitsky.org/projects/listbox.js/en/...

Comment: looks like it could be worth a shot, let us know how you get on with it.